# Looping through all subfolders, zipping each folder in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to zip each sub folder in a root folder (InputFolder) on another folder (OutputFolder)

That's the folder structure i have:

- Root

  - 001
  - 002
  - 003
  - ...
  - 020
  - 021
  - ...
  - 095

Each folder have a number of files between **5.000** and **15.000**

I try the code below, but it's not performing and i didn't know if it will create the zip file.

```
param
(
  # The input folder containing the files to zip
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  [string] $InputFolder,

  # The output folder that will contain the zip files
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  [string] $OutputFolder
)

#Set-Variable SET_SIZE -option Constant -value 10

$subfolders = Get-ChildItem $InputFolder -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }


ForEach ($s in $subfolders) {

  $path = $s  #$s variable contains each folder
  $path 
  Set-Location $path.FullName

  $fullpath = $path.FullName
  $pathName = $path.BaseName

  #Get all items 
  $items = Get-ChildItem

  #Verify that there are such items in this directory, catch errors
  if ( $(Try { Test-Path $items } 
   Catch { "Cannot find items in $fullpath. 
   Sub-folders will be processed afterwards. 
   ERROR: $_" >>  "$InputtFolder\OutputLog.txt"  }) ) {

    $newpath = $OutputFolder + "\" + $pathName
    $newpath
    # Create directory if it doesn't exsist
    if (!(Test-Path $newpath))
    {
        $newfld = New-Item -ItemType Directory 
          -Path $OutputFolder -Name $pathName
    }

    $src = $newfld.FullName

    #move items to newly-created folder
    Move-Item $items -destination $src 

    $dest = "$src.zip"
    "Compressing $src to $dest"  >>  "$InputFolder\OutputLog.txt"  

    #the following block zips the folder
    try{
        $zip = New-Object ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.FastZip
        $zip.CreateZip($dest, $src, $true, ".*")
        Remove-Item $src -force -recurse
    }
    catch { 
        "Folder could not be compressed. Removal of $src ABORTED. 
        ERROR: $_" >> "$InputFolder/OutputLog.txt" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ERROR: Não é possível localizar o tipo [ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.FastZip]: verifique se o o assembly contendo o tipo está carregado.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
function Compress-Subfolders
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $InputFolder,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $OutputFolder
    )

    $subfolders = Get-ChildItem $InputFolder | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }

    ForEach ($s in $subfolders) 
    {
        $path = $s
        $path
        Set-Location $path.FullName
        $fullpath = $path.FullName
        $pathName = $path.BaseName

        #Get all items 
        $items = Get-ChildItem

        $zipname = $path.name + ".zip"
        $zippath = $outputfolder + $zipname
        Compress-Archive -Path $items -DestinationPath $zippath
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Compress-Subfolders -InputFolder c:\your\input\path\ -OutputFolder c:\your\output\path\
```

The Outputfolder has to exist (You can alter the code above to check and create the folder, if it not exists).

You can copy and paste the function in your scriptfile above the rest of the code.

Greetings, Ronny

Comment: I ran this script and it works fine. However the inbuilt powershell zip is really slow. I replaced it with this

Compress-Archive -Path $items -DestinationPath $zippath

set-alias sz "$env:C:\7za920\7za.exe"
sz a -mx9 -tzip -r $Items $zippath

Comment: Thanks! Just need to remember the trailing slash on output folder